# How to get data from multiple models in queryset utilizing 'select_related'?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I am trying to get combined queryset for two models, basically a LEFT JOIN for two tables.

I read multiple answers on how to perform LEFT JOIN on querysets and I found that the easiest way is via select_related, so that is what I did.

When I print the raw query, it looks good, it contains information from both tables (both models).

However the returned queryset contains only the information from the first model. I read that this is a default and it can be overridden by get_query. And this is where I am lost, because the documentation provides get_query description only for class based view and so far I worked only with function based views.

These are my models:

```py
    class WorkPlace(models.Model):
        workplace   = models.TextField(unique=True)
        nickname    = models.TextField(null=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.workplace}'

    class Status(models.Model):
        workplace   = models.OneToOneField(WorkPlace, to_field="workplace", db_column="workplace", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
        status      = models.TextField()

        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.status}'
```

This it the view:

```py
    def work_place_list_view(request):
        qs1 = WorkPlace.objects.select_related('status')
        print(qs1.query)
        context = {"workplace_list": qs1, "title": "Seznam pracovišť"}
        template_name = 'megavisor/workplace_list.html'
        return render(request, template_name, context)
```

This is the raw query from console:

```
SELECT "megavisor_workplace"."id", "megavisor_workplace"."workplace", "megavisor_workplace"."nickname", "megavisor_status"."id", "megavisor_status"."workplace", "megavisor_status"."status" FROM "megavisor_workplace" LEFT OUTER JOIN "megavisor_status" ON ("megavisor_workplace"."workplace" = "megavisor_status"."workplace")
```

The output is the queryset containing only the information from model of class WorkPlace. I need it to contain also the information from model of class WorkPlaceStatus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add related name in workplace.

```
 workplace   = models.OneToOneField(WorkPlace,  related_name="work", to_field="workplace", db_column="workplace", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

then, use this this query,

```
qs1 = WorkPlace.objects.select_related('work')
```

and, you cannot use `status` in select_related because your foreign key was `workplace`.

Comment: Working! Thank you, related_name did the trick, although I put it in the wrong place before.